# How to use coin-slider plugin dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, coin-flipping

i have used coin slider for my application.My application supported for all resolution .But if i wants to use coin-slider i have to be set width or else it takes its default width 585.But according to my application i have to be set width dynamically for all resolutions.For this i have used width:auto property.If i used this property coin-slider is not working.How can i resolve this issue?My code :

```
 > function coinSlide(id) {
    >                     id = '#'+id.replace(/:/g, "\\:");
    >                     var sliderWidth="auto";
    >                     alert("Width : "+sliderWidth);
    >                 <%--sliderWidth = 60em;--%>
    >                         jQuery(id).coinslider({width:sliderWidth,height:screen.height/4,delay:500});
    >                     }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coinslider needs fixed height & width, because it counts the particle divs from that. It divides the image area into smaller divs (these divs are on the top of the image), and every div has the same background image (the new image) with different background position. Once it counted, the animation starts.

So for these position countings, you must have fixed size base area.

Comment: Hi Pinu,If i give the above code it run and its change the slide.But without effects and navigation.How is possible?Is there any other plugin avail for use in the dynamic environmen(i.e) various resolutions by giving width:auto?

Comment: I think this happens because after the animation sequence, the base image changing to the new one (and the next image will be divided into the particle divs). But, because you dont have fixed width, you cannot see the animation (0 height 0 width in the particle divs), but it runs. The navigation arrows are in the particle divs, so that why you cant see that too.

Comment: I dont know any other plugin like coinslider, except my own experimental, but that one is based on coinslider. sorry